# Make me a pizza

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Because it's Saturday (UTC) and I'm hungry, I would like a slice of pizza. I will give you an order and I would like a nice hot [ascii-art](/questions/tagged/ascii-art) pizza. Up to the challenge?

### The Drive-Thru

I'll place my order wherever your drive-thru is, whether it is STDIN, a function parameter, a command-line argument, but I'm not going to put it in a variable for you. (JS function expressions must be assigned to a variable.)

### The order

My order will have 2 parts. The first will be a positive, non-zero integer from `3` to `6`. This is the size of my pizza. For instance, a size `6` pizza with no toppings would look like:

```
 /=====\
/       \
|       |
|       |
\       /
 \=====/
```

A size `5`:

```
 /====\
/      \
|      |
\      /
 \====/
```

A size `4`:

```
 /===\
|     |
|     |
 \===/
```

A size `3`

```
 /==\
|    |
 \==/
```

### The toppings

My toppings will be a string of UPPERCASE letters. Here are the possible values:

```
P - Pepperoni
S - Sausage
N - piNeapple
J - Jalapenos
B - Banana peppers
C - baCon
```

You must fit them on the pizza somewhere. If I order a size 4 and `PSPCJ`, then this is a valid output:

```
 /===\
|PSPCJ|
|     |
 \===/
```

So is this:

```
 /===\
|P P J|
| S C |
 \===/
```

And this:

```
 /===\
|     |
|PSPCJ|
 \===/
```

I am not really picky about where my toppings are on the pizza, as long as they aren't on the crust or on top of each other.

### The pick-up window

I will go to a lot of places to pick up my pizza, including STDOUT, a file, the return value of a function, but not a variable.

### Extra stuff

- Standard loopholes forbidden
- **This is tagged [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins!**
- Don't worry about invalid input (toppings > pizza space, etc.)
- See my answer (JS ES6) below for an example (I hope you can do better)

Comment: Umm, So you can also pick your pizza up on a Drive-thru?

Comment: Are you picky about me filling the top right and bottom right corners of the pizza box with whitespace? ;)

Comment: @DLosc no, any trailing whitespace at the end of any line (including a trailing newline at the end of output) is optional but not required.

Comment: C̶a̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶i̶z̶z̶a̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶m̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶n̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶p̶p̶i̶n̶g̶s̶?̶ ̶S̶o̶ ̶i̶f̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶p̶i̶n̶e̶a̶p̶p̶l̶e̶:̶ ̶`̶5̶,̶ ̶N̶N̶N̶`̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶a̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶p̶u̶t̶ ̶(̶o̶r̶ ̶s̶h̶o̶u̶l̶d̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶ ̶`̶5̶,̶ ̶N̶`̶ ̶i̶n̶s̶t̶e̶a̶d̶)̶?̶ Also, where are the mushrooms?.. :( EDIT: Nevermind about the first question, I see your test cases has 2x `P`.

Comment: Can I post an [orderup](https://orderup.com/some/northern/delivery/pizza) link? xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>87</s> <s>81</s> 75 bytes

74 bytes of code, +1 for `-l` flag.

```
e:'/.'=Xa-1.'\Y['/'\]Xa//5J'|X2-a%2^xPs.ePy.(b.sXa*a-a-2-#b<>a+1).RVys.RVe
```

Takes input as command-line arguments. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@59qpa6vp24bkahrqKceExmtrq8eExuRqK9v6qVeE2Gkm6hqFFcRUKyXGlCpp5GkVxyRqJWom6hrpKucZGOXqG2oqRcUVlkMJFL///@vm/Pf9L@fk58fCAdDaT8nAA)

#### Approach

`e` is the top row, such as `/=====\`. If you reverse it, it's also the bottom row.

`y` is the left border, such as `["/" "|" "|" "\"]`. If you reverse it, it's also the right border.

We then construct the middle by taking `b`, the toppings, padding it with spaces to length `(a+1)*(a-2)` (where `a` is the size), and grouping it into a list of rows.

Finally, we print the top row with a leading space; concatenate the middle between `y` on the left and `RVy` on the right, and print that; and print the bottom row with a leading space.

Comment: Does this work with a cheese (no toppings) pizza?

Comment: @programmer5000 Yes--in that case the second cmdline arg should be an empty string (if you're running it from an actual command-line, you'll have to quote it).

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>202,198,190,177,162,157,</s>146 bytes

```python
n,t=input()
y=n+1
s=' '
l=' /'+'='*(n-1)+'\\ '+('','\n/'+s*y+'\\')[n>4]+'\n|'
print l+t[:y].center(y,s)+('','|\n|'+t[y:].center(y,s))[y%2]+l[::-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#VYuxCsIwGIT3PEUXuaRJlIo4BOKgm4MIjmkGKYUWym9p4xDoazvHFCeX4@O@u0Qq2J7Gd@CCRUuyYrNFATbk3EHCouSkKyFR1wUkBxRqymYu49pBODodfEZawMapp1AMMjgT/bZpKbQTj2oWv@OyjrKM5k8KFzd7LwdnjK58SkeF@@N2PV/woZdunk3XfgE)

Comment: Hey, can you assign `'\\'`, `'|`', and `'/` to variables to golf off a few bytes? That's how I shaved a lot off my JS answer.

Comment: I'm just working on that!!!!

Comment: Also, can you replace the first `(n-1)` with `(--n)`, the `n>4`s with`n>3`, `(n+1)` with `(n+2)`, and the final `(n-1)` with `n` to shave off 4 bytes?

Comment: python doesnt support `--` operator !

Comment: [136 bytes](https://tio.run/##TYuxCsIwFEX3fkUWuU1fqrSIQyAOujmI4JhmkoKF8CwlDg@Kvx5bXNwu55w7Snq@uM2ZTXIDj@9U6kIcU1NEB7UDwaH61EzoOgUqAYOOV65QyUqhPR/3YZk8oxingZOKlLyVsH30nPqpFP07zmuyKLF/SnvZtIGit7ZuQs4Hg9v9ejmd8QU "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>224</s> <s>213</s> 195 bytes

```python
n,t=eval(input())
k=n+1
y=print
i=0
f,s,e,b,p="/ =\\|"
t+=s*99
y(s+f+e*~-n+b)
if n>4:y(f+t[:k]+b);i+=k
y(p+t[i:i+k]+p);i+=k
if~-n%2:y(p+t[i:i+k]+p);i+=k
if n>4:y(b+t[i:i+k]+f);i+=k
y(s+b+e*~-n+f)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#dY3LCsIwEEX3@YoSEJJOxAfdNDJuFfUPrAsDHRgqIZgoFMRfj1kUXbk95z6yNwn75/Wm2IdHUlqLAT2sxIjhzj4JxqUgE01vnAkoFxV23UuKBBjrthWjikDQ1@@5B6cFU@W3jR0VQTrb4VLYhgGHkguFsGUoMEyQqdRma/tHTlPu5@i7FsFNr6Rzbow8HPe7k/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 37 bytes

```
Ｎθ /==×=⸿/›θ⁴⸿|‖ＢＯ↓﹪θ²‖ＢＯ⊕﹪θ²Ｊ¹¦¹⪪Ｓ⊕θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY@xDoIwEIZ3n6Lp1CY1BMOkYVETA4lKhJGlwqEkpYXaYkx89woOaBwc78/33X9XXLkuFBfORbK15mCbM2jS0dUs0bU0BCMvDPE0ZnUDN4LDXHuYoZ0GbkacoYDSj5Pr56icoBJQmLU1A1SJx7EHLXhLllt1lwztVWmFGuUF/UNHstDQgDRQkh8ltk2bKeIz5E/laStqQ97PpGZILoQy9L2jGy91LpglabKJ3bwXLw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input the size of the pizza.

```
 /==
```

Start printing the top of the pizza.

```
×=⸿/›θ⁴
```

If the pizza is one of the larger sizes, add extra to the top and side.

```
⸿|
```

Print more of the side of the pizza.

```
‖ＢＯ↓﹪θ²
```

Complete the left half of the pizza by reflection with possible overlap.

```
‖ＢＯ⊕﹪θ²
```

Complete the pizza by reflection with variable overlap.

```
Ｊ¹¦¹⪪Ｓ⊕θ
```

Input the toppings and split them into pieces so they will fit inside the pizza.

Answer (score 0):

## JS (ES6), <strike>257</strike> <strike>255</strike> <strike>249</strike> <strike>248</strike> <strike>246</strike> 244 bytes

```
m=s=>t=>(r="/",k="\\",p=" ",f="\n",x="|",c=f+x,q="",t=p+t,z=(s>2?p:q)+r+"=".repeat(s-1)+k+(s>4?f+r+p.repeat(++s)+k:q)+c+p.repeat(s)+x+(!s?c+p.repeat(s)+x:q)+p+(s>5?f+k+p.repeat(s)+r:q)+f+p+k+"=".repeat(s-2)+r,i=-1,z.replace(/ /g, x=>t[++i]||p))
```

Call it like `m(4)("PS")` for 1 pepperoni and 1 sausage. Probably can be golfed more.

Comment: Jeez, give some other people time to answer :P

Comment: @Григорий Перельман I just wanted to provide an example, I hope this doesn't win.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>170</s> 161 bytes

```
(n,t,a=[1,,n%2||2,,1])=>` /=\\
/___\\
|___|
\\___/
 \\=/`[r=`replace`](/.+/g,s=>s.repeat(a.pop()||n>4))[r](/=|_\b/g,`$&`.repeat(n-1))[r](/_/g,_=>t[i++]||` `,i=0)
```

Starts by taking a misshapen pizza of width 2 and height 5 and stretches it horizontally and adjusts it vertically as appropriate, then replaces the interior with toppings or spaces once they run out.